# SQL - Join tables with modified data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So, I have two tables in SQL Sever 2008 R2:

```
 Table A:

 patient_id   first_name   last_name   external_id
 000001       John         Smith       4753-23314.0
 000002       Mike         Davis       4753-12548.0

 Table B:

 guarantor_id   visit_date   first_name   last_name
 23314          01/01/2013   John         Smith
 12548          02/02/2013   Mike         Davis
```

Notice that the guarantor_id from Table B matches the middle section of the external_id from Table A. Would someone please help me strip the 4753- from the front and the .0 from the back of the external_id so I can join these tables?

Any help/examples is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the prefix and suffix are always the same length, just do this:

```
SUBSTRING(external_id, 6, 5)
```

The documentation for `SUBSTRING` is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) if you want to look at that.

If the prefix and suffix change, also use [CHARINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) AND [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx).

```
SUBSTRING(external_id, CHARINDEX(external_id,'-') + 1, CHARINDEX(external_id,'.') - CHARINDEX(external_id,'-') + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A inner join TABLE_B on TABLE_A.external_id like '%'+TABLE_B.guarantor_id+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works. :)

```
select LEFT(right(external_id, 7), 5)
from table_a
```

Comment: This is what I wound up using. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As @woz said, you can use SUBSTRING, if the length is not fixed, you can use the CHARINDEX function, to determine the positions of the dot and dash to make it more flexible.

On another note, joining based on a function will heavily degrade your performance, I suggest updating the field with the function result, or creating a new column STRIPPED_GUARANTOR_ID that has the stripped value, then joining on that column

Answer (score 0):

use substring and charindex.  So long as you are looking for the value between the first '-' and '.' characters...

```
SUBSTRING (
           externalid,
           CHARINDEX('-',externalid)+1, 
           CHARINDEX('.',externalid)-CHARINDEX('-',externalid) 
          )
```